# java.lang.NullPointerException error message when I try to populate table in java swing with database data

Tags: java, sql, swing

I tried to populate jTable in java swing with the data inside my database table. Here are the codes which I set up the connection.

```
    package DBController.database;

    import java.sql.*;

    public class DBController {
private Connection con;

public void setUp(String dsn) {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Load driver error");
    }
    try {

        String s = "jdbc:odbc:" + dsn;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(s, "", "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ResultSet readRequest(String dbQuery) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(dbQuery);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs;
}

public int updateRequest(String dbQuery) {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        count = stmt.executeUpdate(dbQuery);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return count;
}

public void terminate() {
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And here are the codes which I tried to write for the sql statement.

```
    public boolean retrieveDiscussion() {
    boolean success = false;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM forumTopics WHERE topic_description = '" + description
            + "' and topic_category = '" + category
            + "' and topic_title = '" + title 
            + "' and topic_by = '" + postedBy + "'";
    rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);
    db.terminate();
    return success;
}
```

Here is the codes for my table in user interface.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // The Connection is obtained

    eForumTopics topics = new eForumTopics();
    topics.retrieveDiscussion();

    // It creates and displays the table
    JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(null));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));

    // Closes the Connection
}
public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
throws SQLException {

    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }

    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    }
```

However, when I tried to run the application, it gave me

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

error message. So what am I supposed to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please give the full stack trace of the error i.e line number etc. Also create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with random values etc, as we cannot test code for which we dont have the tables etc

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at kioskeForum.ui.eForumDiscussion.buildTableModel(eForumDiscussion.java:271)
 at kioskeForum.ui.eForumDiscussion.main(eForumDiscussion.java:262)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the bug is

```
JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(null));
```

Comment: But after I removed the null, the buildTableModel will have error. If I remove the ResultSet rs from public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel, all the 'rs' after that will have error.

Comment: Actually I took the code from some website. These are the full codes.

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // The Connection is obtained

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from product_info");

    // It creates and displays the table
    JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));

    // Closes the Connection
}

However,at the stmt there, the error message asked me cast something. I do not know how the cast Object thing works. Even I researched also no answer.